Going cold after coffee chat
I recently reached out to someone at a company that I am interested at. This person who happened to live near me, offered a coffee chat to discuss the industry and my job search in general and also mentioned that her team may have some positions opening in 6 months or so. We had a good discussion during our coffee chat; and she brought up a bit more details about her team, the opportunities and mentioned that she'd follow up with higher ups to explore a potential position for me. At the end, she also mentioned to reach out anytime with questions as I go through my interviews. I followed up the next day with an email thanking her for her time and expressing my interest in a position with her company. I never got a response. About a month later, I followed up again asking for some advice and again subtly expressing my interest in a role with her company and again no response.
I am not sure how to go from here. I was so excited about a potential opening with this company and thought i had a good chat with her. Any advice or relative experiences would be much appreciated.
To be clear, I did not have a formal interview. By posting this, i.e. THE GOAL, is to get some insights on why she never responded after a long, friendly and warm conversation? In your experience, I did something that killed my potential as a candidate for the position or perhaps she's busy and want to have a solid path/green light to move forward after discussing with her colleagues? I also looking to find out if this is a common occurrence or more rare.

This question is similar to: How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks, the situation i described is very different. I try to make it more clear.

Honestly, it's not different. You had an informal interview, they're not responding. The answer is the same - time to move on. Nobody here can tell you why somebody else is taking the actions they are.

@user147813 - Philip is 100 percent correct here, as crappy as it is, you move on.

@user147813 - Calling community users ignorant isn’t very nice especially if you want them to answer your question.

"her team may have some positions opening in 6 months or so" What is it you're expecting to happen expressing interest well before any openings might open, which she already indicated to you?

As said before, the question is not about what i should do or help me move on. It's about drawing on the collective experience here to figure out if i can do better next time and if this is a common experience or more rare; which gives me some insights for my future informal interviews. The comments to "move on" misses the point. The moderators also seem a bit power hungry here by closing down the question. The goal of my question is clear and i'd like to hear others reflections and experiences. You don't have anything to add, then don't.

It's a common experience. You didn't do anything wrong except putting too much weight on this informal conversation. "Reflections and experiences" is, unfortunately, out of scope for Stack Exchange except as illustration of specific answers.

@user147813 - Please be respectful of the community, asking us to essentially “shut up”, if we are unwilling to agree with your point of view, is unkind and definitely strange if you want the communities viewpoint on your situation

what point am i asking you to agree with? please be specific.

OK, if "reflection and experiences" are out of the scope then i'll delete my question. But by that definition, what is in-scope for Stack Exchange when not dealing with objective, quantifiable calculations/computations questions?

@user147813 - Deleting your question is impossible due to it receiving an answer. Threatening to delete your question isn’t very nice, just because, you don’t like the reception you received so far. Asking a question then deleting the question because its reception isn’t positive behavior, instead of deleting your question, editing and improving your question is positive behavior.

Hi @Donald, first of thanks for your response to my question below. I'm not making threats and I'm certainly not disrespecting the community here. However, I am challenging some comments here as I view them not constructive. I have that right and btw so do the people who are expressing their opinions here. But I can't let go without a challenge broad comments such as "[you are] asking us to shut up (not sure why that's in a quote) if we are unwilling to agree with your point of view" or "Reflections and experiences" are out of the scope of Stack Exchange. My responses to both are respectful.

Also, you are wrong about deleting my question being impossible. Because it is marked to be "off-topic", Stack Exchange is giving me the option to delete, it's a giant hyperlink in red that says "Delete question". I understand that's only visible to me but had to clarify your comment.

@user147813 - Please just improve your question instead of deleting your question. Saying you’re going to just delete your question, is threatening to delete your question, but I reached the end of my ability to participate in this conversation. “You don't have anything to add, then don't” - Is asking us to shut up…I won’t be returning due to your attitude, if you want to delete this question go ahead


also mentioned that her team may have some positions opening in 6
months or so.

It is unclear if the job will be posted in 6 months, or they will want somebody to start in 6 months.
Either way that opening, if it happens at all, is not happening soon.

About a month later, I followed up again asking for some advice and
again subtly expressing my interest in a role with her company and
again no response. I am not sure how to go from here. I was so excited
about a potential opening with this company and thought i had a good
chat with her.

People ghost other people all the time. In your case they may feel they have provided the information you needed, and there is nothing for them to do until that job becomes available.
If you need a job now, I hope you are applying to other places. If you don't need a job now, you can wait a few months before reaching out again.

In your experience, I did something that killed my potential as a
candidate for the position or perhaps she's busy and want to have a
solid path/green light to move forward after discussing with her
colleagues?

Anything is possible. They could have decided you aren't a good fit. They could have thrown your contact info into the pile with all the other people look for jobs. No way we can know.

Individuals feel compelled to not directly reject someone especially if they meet you in person. It’s impossible to know if the ghosting is because the position has not yet been created or there is some other human element to the fact they didn’t respond. Our best advice is continue to search for a position elsewhere and everywhere until you hear back.

Something to maybe note, too, is that people are also not obligated to follow up on “what if” scenarios of potential roles that could open up. OP is putting a lot of faith into this person they met, which is unfortunately something I’ve fallen victim to as well. It’s unfortunate but it’s a lesson to be learnt that no one in business is always looking out for your best interests.
